# Substitution for MAXIFS without array formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

After a query is completed, I am inserting the following formula into the sheet with the query data using the vba code below.  All works great on Excel Office365 but if the version of Excel is 2016 standalone the formula fails with a #NAME error as this function is not available in that version.  I have some users that are stuck with it.

I know that a formula array could replace this, but I am not sure how to do this and insert it with code, as well as what the most efficient formula is that could replace this one.

```
 =IF(OR(ISERROR(MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2)),
MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2)=0),"",
MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2))
```

Any help appreciated.

```
strInsertFormula = "=IF(OR(ISERROR(MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2)),MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2)=0),"""",MAXIFS(Consumed!D:D,Consumed!B:B,A2))"

With Sheet3

 .Range("Individual_Bottles").Columns(.Range("EndRng").Offset(0, 1).Column).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
 .Range("EndRng").Offset(-1, 1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Last Drank"
 .Range("EndRng").Offset(0, 1).Formula = strInsertFormula
 .Range("EndRng").Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "yy/mm/dd" 

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnF Well I got it working thanks to John F.  I had expected that I would have to use a loop but was hoping not to.  In the end I did, as I believe the FillDown method requires the range to be selected and I did not want to do that.  Here is the final code

```
        ii = .Range("EndRng").rows.Count
        ConsRows = Consumed.Range("Consumed").rows.Count

        For i = 1 To ii
            strInsertFormula = "=IF(IFERROR(MAX(IF(Consumed!B1:B" & ConsRows & "=" & _
                .Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
                ",Consumed!D1:D" & ConsRows & ","""")),0)>0,MAX(IF(Consumed!B1:B" & ConsRows & "=" & _
                .Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
                ",Consumed!D1:D" & ConsRows & ","""")),"""")"

            .Range("EndRng").Offset(0, 1).Cells(i, 1).FormulaArray = strInsertFormula
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel Array formula `=MAX(IF(B:B=A2,D:D,""))` to find the conditional maximum (you can add the extra error checks etc. around this). This will work in all versions from 2016 and earlier.

If you type this into a cell, you do need to press the usual Crtl+Shift+Enter (known as CSE).

If you want to enter this array formula via code, you need to set the FormulaArray property of the range to the above, NOT the Formula property. So your code should read:

```
.Range("EndRng").Offset(0, 1).FormulaArray = strInsertFormula
```

where `strInsertFormula` is the array formula I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. That looks like it will work. Here is the full formula wrapped with some error checks. Is there a way to simplify this or make it more efficient? `=IF(OR(ISERROR(MAX(IF(Consumed!B:B=A2,Consumed!D:D,""))),(MAX(IF(Consumed!B:B=A2,Consumed!D:D,"")))=0),"",MAX(IF(Consumed!B:B=A2,Consumed!D:D,"")))`

Comment: for some reason the A2 remains in all rows as if it is an absolute reference.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can make the error checking part more concise using the IFERROR function: =IF(IFERROR(MAX(IF(Consumed!B:B=A2,Consumed!D:D,"")),0)>0,MAX(IF(Consumed!B:B=A2,Consumed!D:D,"")),"")

Comment: Re A2 reference: one way would be to insert the formula in the first row, and then use the autofill method of the cell to fill the formula down as many rows as you need. Another way way would be to work out the address you want via the .Address property and substitute that into strInsertFormula.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  Would you kindly be able to elaborate on using the .Address property.  The other issue is that the sheet is not the active sheet when the code is running.

Comment: Something like instead of IF(Consumed!B:B=A2... you would put IF(Consumed!B:B=" & <range where formula is to go>.Address & " (rest of formula) i.e. use string concatenation to build the formula. If it isn't on the active sheet, you need to say Sheets("<SheetName>").Range("<RangeName">).Address .

Comment: Sorry I am not getting this.  my vba code is `strInsertFormula = "=MAX(IF(Consumed!$B$2:$B$2500=" & .Range("A:A").Address & ",Consumed!$D$2:$D$2500,""""))" ` and I end up with this in each cell of the column `=MAX(IF(Consumed!$B$2:$B$2500=$A:$A,Consumed!$D$2:$D$2500,""))` when the $A:$A should be A2, A3 etc. in each row.

Comment: No you need to use a loop to go through all the cells where you want to fill. Put `strInsertFormula = "=MAX(IF(Consumed!$B$2:$B$2500=" & .Range("A2").Offset(i,0).Address & ",Consumed!$D$2:$D$2500,""""))"` in a `For...To...Next` loop with `i` ranging from 0 to 2500. I think the better approach is to use the FillDown method: put the formula in with the reference to A2, then use the .FillDown method to extend the formula down. If this is confusing, try recording a macro where you fill down the formula and look at the code.

Comment: Here is a sample of how I might do it.
`Sub FormulaFillDown()

    Dim strFormula As String

    
   strFormula = "=MAX(IF($C$2:$C$10=F2,$D$2:$D$10,""""))"
   Range("G2").FormulaArray = strFormula
    Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    
End Sub`